# asp.net GridView dynamic line creation with dropmenu as Textbox entry

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have found a dynamic gridview code that creates lines and saves the one you filled last.

In my code i want to parse the droplist selected value text instead of actually writing in the textbox.

I have managed to parse the selectedvalue text in a textbox and for one line everything goes fine, but when i try to create a second line the selected value becomes the same for both lines.
(example: lets say i have a ddl menu with the values "a,b" if i choose the a value first the textbox will be filled ok "a" value, but if i choose b for the second line it will be both "b".

I will be needing 9 textboxes but i have made a simple version of the code containing only 1 textbox for the sake of space.

HTML

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="height: 337px">
            <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Gridview1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 1">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                
                    <asp:TemplateField >
                        
                        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row"
                                OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>


            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />


        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

C# code

```
namespace WebApplication4
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            setInitialRow();
        }
    }




    protected void Gridview1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }





    protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewRowToGrid();
    }





    private void setInitialRow()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;

        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));


        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
        dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);


        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
        Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
        Gridview1.DataBind();
    }







    private void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");


                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                    drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;


                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column1"] = box1.Text;



                    rowIndex++;

                }

                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                Gridview1.DataBind();

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Viewstate is null");
            }
            SetPreviousData();
        }
    }






    private void SetPreviousData()
    {

        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {

            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");


                    box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();

                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }



    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,   EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

So as you'd imagine i tried going

```
 box1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

I tried with view state, but generally i failed.
Thanks for any of the answers guys!

Comment: Where is your Dropdownlist placed and selected index change event for Dropdownlist ?

Comment: oh sorry you are right , it's in the same page as the gridview, i accidently deleted the line of the droplist when i deleted the code lines to make it smaller. im editing the post right now!

Comment: Where is selected index change event for dropdownlist?

Comment: ok this is exactly as i had it before. I tried putting the parse in the selectedindex event, but still the values became the same...

Comment: How? Please share your code. You need to find specific textbox from gridview to show dropdown selected text at textbox.

How you find box1?

Comment: if you read the c# code  TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");  It's found as a control of the gridview cause the creation is dynamic, there's no actual textbox1 it's stated in the HTML code only as a template.

Comment: If you want to set dropdown selected value totextbox then there should be Selected Index change event for dropdown list. Where is it?

Comment: it's the last method on c# code.. but if you have selected the value from the dropdown list then you can use DropDownlist1.SelectedValue.ToString(); somewhere in the code and get the value !.  Anyways the event handler is the last on the C# code

Comment: Please see my answer. And try.
Need to add AutoPostBack="true" for dropdown.
And try codebehind code given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASPX Page

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetPreviousData();
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {

            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[(dt.Rows.Count - 1)].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                box1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Another Approach you can try is you can directly place dropdownlist in gridview instead of textbox.

Comment: suuuuper thanks man! works like a charm, can you explain the answer a bit? thaaanks anyways man!